# Problem with Preview using TeXlipse in Mac OS Snow Leopard

Tags: mactex, texlipse, eclipse

I basically configured everything as indicated in this [website](http://blog.to-fuse.ch/os-x/install-mactex-with-texlipse-on-os-x/) but I cannot get to preview my document.

When I click on Latex > Preview Document I get an error message indicating:

> Launching preview document in yap' has encountered a problem.  Could
>   not start previewer yap.  Please make sure you have entered the
>   correct path and filename in the viewer preferences

Details are:

> Could not start previewer 'yap'. Please make sure you have entered the
>   correct path and filename in the viewer preferences. Cannot run
>   program "" (in directory "/Users/ohd/Documents/workspace/Seminar"):
>   error=2, No such file or directory

This is one of the preview programs listed on the Viewer Settings, but I have acroread in the 1st place.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

`/usr/local/texlive/2008/bin/universal`- I believe "yap" (short for "yet another previewer", right?) is a dvi file previewer for Windows machines. You should check out the section "Using preview to source linking on Mac OS X" of the online manual for TeXlipse (at bottom of http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/build.html) for information on using MacOSX's own Preview program or Adobe's acroread.

Addendum: I just checked out the installation instructions on the website you mention, and they seem to be 2 to 3 years out of date. For instance, instead of using the path `/usr/local/texlive/2008/bin/universal-darwin`, as suggested in the instructions, you'll want to use `/usr/local/texlive/2008/bin/universal-x86_64-darwin` -- assuming you've loaded the latest version of TeXLive.

Comment: I check the link you posted (the one with the section 'Using preview to source linking on Mac OS X') but still I have issues.  First, I cannot start iTexMac after I've installed it (Error Message: iTexMac quit unexpectedly), I have also modified the paths according to your addendum (not the same path but using the newest version)

Comment: If I do Latex > Preview Document, I get the following message:  running: /usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/iTeXMac 1.3.15/iTeXMac.app" document.pdf
viewer> FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/iTeXMac 1.3.15/iTeXMac.app) failed with error -43.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the blog post mentioned in the question. Mico, is right, the instructions are a bit outdated, but still seem to work if you specify the paths according to the installed version of MacTeX. I updated the post with the path directives found in Mico's answer. Please also leave a feedback or question on my blog if you find any issues. Thank you very much - rico

Comment: I modified the paths.  According to http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/build.html (section "Using preview ..." at the bottom) I need iTexMac.
Im not able to start iTexMac after I've installed it, it just simply crashes. Also, if I try to preview in Eclipse (considering the issue with iTexMac) I get this error message:
running: /usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/iTeXMac 1.3.15/iTeXMac.app" document.pdf
viewer> FSPathMakeRef(/Applications/iTeXMac 1.3.15/iTeXMac.app) failed with error -43.
So I have no idea about what can be wrong...Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about iTexMac app. But, you can change viewer (setting):

- Viewer Command box: `"/usr/bin/open"`
- Viewer Argument: `%file`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have set 'dvi' as output format in the project preferences while you have no dvi viewer configured. Acroread can only show .pdf files, so you have to change your output format to .pdf in the LaTeX project properties.